# How is the dual cone of a subspace its orthogonal complement?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

From Boyd and Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization*:

> A dual cone of a subspace $V \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ is it's orthogonal
>   complement.
>
> $V^{*} = \{y : v^Ty = 0, \forall v \in V\}$

but the dual cone is defined by: $V^{*} = \{y : v^Ty \ge 0, \forall v \in V\}$.

Why are there no vectors $v$ such that $v^Ty > 0$?

Comment: 'Complement', not 'compliment'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y\in V^*$ and assume that there exists $v\in V$ such that $y^Tv >0.$ Since $V$ is a subspace, it follows that $-v \in V.$ But then

$$0\leq y^T(-v)= -y^Tv<0,$$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $y \in V^*$ and $v^Ty > 0$ then $(-v)^Ty < 0$ contradicting $y \in V^*$.